# What is the correct syntax to pass variable into mutation in graphql

Tags: react-native, graphql

I have a react native app.

What is the correct syntax in graphql to pass **variable** into **customerCreate**?

```
const url = 'https://xxxx.myshopify.com/api/graphql';
const query = `
    var variable = {
          "input": {
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "password": "pass"
          }
    }

    mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
      customerCreate(input: $input) {
        userErrors {
          field
          message
        }
        customer {
          id
        }
      }
    }
`;
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
.catch(err => {
    console.log('-- gql err --')
    console.error(err);
})
```

Comment: seems like you are using Shopify GraphQL support, so your question goes beyond the basics of GraphQL.
You could try using the Javascript client library Shopify offers https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-js-client I think it'll do your life easier

Comment: Your GraphQL syntax looks right but you're missing the `variables:` in the HTTP request body; compare https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request

Comment: Please paste the contents of `input CustomerCreateInput {/* content */}` here. It'd be also useful to know what exact error are you getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to pass variables into mutation could be by doing something like:

```
const url = 'https://xxxx.myshopify.com/api/graphql';
const query = `
    mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
      customerCreate(input: $input) {
        userErrors {
          field
          message
        }
        customer {
          id
        }
      }
    }
`;
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
        query: query,
        variables: {
           input: {
             email: "test@test.com",
             password: "pass"
           }
        }, 
    }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
.catch(err => {
    console.log('-- gql err --')
    console.error(err);
})
```

And just make sure the `variables` object inside `JSON.stringify` have to match the type `CustomerCreateInput`.